# Getting a SSL Handshake exception, trying to perform SSL in android app

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have an api provided with a HTTPS connection, I followed this blog,(https://www.netguru.com/codestories/3-ways-how-to-implement-certificate-pinning-on-android), specifically steps 2 and 3 to apply certificate pinning but none of the methods work. This is what I've done so far:

1. Create the network_security_config.xml file
2. Add it to the manifest
3. Set up the configuration file and added fingerprints by generating them with https://github.com/scottyab/ssl-pin-generator

However, I only get an SSL Handshake Exception error (*NativeCrypto_SSL_do_handshake exception => 0*), without any further details or specific error. How can I integrate this in the app?

Comment: Did you change your android device date ?